# Page numbering inconsistency fncychap package

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fncychap

I am using `fncychap` package to align my chapters for my dissertation as per university requirements. But the challenge I am facing now is inconsistent page numbering. I want page numbering to be on the right corner. Below is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{fncychap}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase %  also for "Table of content" etc.
\ChNameVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}
\ChNumVar{\normalsize\mdseries}
\ChTitleVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}

% following is inspired by pages 8-9 of the manual of the fncychap package
% Adding of \vspace{-3cm} to move up the word "CHAPTER" and his number
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
\vspace{-3cm}\CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter\par\nobreak 
\vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}{\mdseries}

\centerline{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CHAPTER}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage 

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}

hdhdhdhdhhddh
\section{Motivation}

\newpage
\section{methods}

hdhdhdh


\end{document}
```

The list of tables has page numbering in the footer while page 6 is on the top right.
[image: Code result]

The expected format should be page numbering on the right corner for all pages including the table of contents, list of tables, and no other information. I tried `fancyhdr` but it seems it is not working together with `fncychap`. Please help.
[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 1):

It works with **fancyhdr**. But you need to add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` before the end of the first page of a chapter. By default the first page of a chapter has his page number in the footer, but with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` we ask that the first page use the *fancy* style, which is defined below (with only a page number on the right side of the header of the page, and no footer).

As Table of content, List of figure are similar of a new chapter in the *book* document class, we also need to add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` before the end of the first page of these specials sectionning.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\usepackage{fncychap} 
\ChNameUpperCase 
\ChTitleUpperCase % also for "Table of content" etc. 
\ChNameVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering} 
\ChNumVar{\normalsize\mdseries} 
\ChTitleVar{\normalsize\mdseries\centering}

% following is inspired by pages 8-9 of the manual of the fncychap package 
% Adding of \vspace{-3cm} to move up the word "CHAPTER" and his number 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{% 
\vspace{-3cm}\CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV\thechapter\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@} 
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{% 
\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@} 
\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{% 
\vspace{-3cm}\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak \vskip 10\p@} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % to customize the header
\pagestyle{fancy} % uses the `fancy` style
\fancyhf{} % wipe the default settings
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % page number on the right side
\renewcommand\headrule{} % no line between the head and the body
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % to remove a warning

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}{\mdseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}

\thispagestyle{fancy} % to use fancy style on this page

\tableofcontents 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENT}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

hdhdhdhdhhddh 

\section{Motivation}

\lipsum[1-10] 

\section{Methods}

hdhdhdh

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** adding some fake text + modifying the display of the table of contents, but note that chapter-like entries are displayed bold, don't know if this is what you want.

**Edit 2:** After a request in the comment, added `\vspace{-3cm}` on `\DOTIS` command, so the starred `\chapter*` (and titles like Table of content) are also shifted up to the top of the page.

Some examples of the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This is working for the introduction, but it is not working on list of table and list of figures.

Comment: @Roshni I have slightly modified the code for a better table of content.

Comment: How do I remove space from the upper margin in the table of content, and list of tables? Make it consistent with other pages.

Comment: Finally done. Table of content, List of figure, list of table are like starred chapter, so I have to act on `\DOTIS` (which format the `\chapter*` title).